# Adding list items to favorite facing error, doesn't persist state

Tags: android, listview, favorites

I have a method to add favorites from a search list.

This code allows to click on listview and call listener accordingly weather it is search listview or mytour Listview.

```
holder.imgaddFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (tourList.get(position).getFav().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                                              listener.onFavourited(tourList.get(position), true);
                        holder.imgaddFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.faved);
                    } else {
                        listener.onFavourited(tourList.get(position), false);
                        holder.imgFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_faved);
                    }
                }
        });
```

Below is the code for mytourList which works perfectly:

```
@Override
    public void onFavourited(final Tour tour, final boolean fav) {
        new SetFavourite(new SetFavourite.OnFavouriteSet() {
            @Override
            public void onFavouriteSet(Boolean response) {
                int index = listTour.indexOf(tour);
                tour.setFav(fav ? "1" : "0");
                listTour.set(index, tour);
            }
        }, fav).execute(tour.getId(), application.getUser().getUid());
    }
```

This code persist favourite state and got no problem.

Below is my code for adding favorites for search items list.

```
public void onFavourited(final Tour tour, final boolean fav) {

int index = searchOptions.getSearchedTours().indexOf(tour);
tour.setFav(fav ? "1" : "0");
searchOptions.getSearchedTours().get(index).setFav(fav ? "1" : "0");
searchOptions.getSearchedTours().set(index, tour);
}
```

I am able to click on and add it to favorites, but if I open another tab and reopen that list again, the state is lost. I guess it is cause it's not saving state globally. I've searched for similar answers but none of them helped.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In `holder.imgaddFavourite.setOnClickListener`, you call `tourList.get()` but in `public void onFavourited` you call `listTour.set()`. Those two lists seem to be **global** as they are not the arguments of the methods. If that is not the cause of your problem, then you may need to clarify your question for what they are? when/where they are declared? how they are initialized/assigned values? Otherwise it is impossible to check the scope of the lists. Hope that helps!

Comment: @I_A_Mok Hey those are API call methods for adding to favourites and getting favourite from list.

Comment: @I_A_Mok I've added bit more code though. Please let  me know if you can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the state of wheather an item is favourite or not in a Boolean variable which is not a persistent storage. It will not be same when you close and reopen the app.

You should store the favourite items on SharedPreferences or in SQL Database which are persistent storage. In that way you can add and remove the data anytime you want, and it will be persisted.

Hope this helps, if you have any doubt, do let me know.

Comment: I've updated code in question. it should save value now after I made API call(tour.setFav(fav ? "1" : "0")). Still it's doesn't persist state.

Comment: Can you update the question with full code, your listview, Activity, what is searchOptions and all so that i can get a better picture of what's happening.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Can you upload full code where you are creating this SearchOptions object and also your full listview adapter. It's difficult to understand the root cause just by seeing pieces of code. :)

Comment: Can you show me what you are writing in onBindViewHolder() function of RecyclerView, and also tell me that these lists are in Fragment which can be changed through viewpager ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using ViewPager to handle fragments and always create new fragment when page changed. Therefore state cannot be retained. Try below method in the adapter of ViewPager:

1. Add variable to keep your desired fragment.

   ```
   SearchTourFragment searchTourFragment = null;
   ```
2. In getItem(), create your desired fragment only when it is null.

   ```
   if(searchTourFragment == null){
       searchTourFragment = SearchTourFragment.newInstance();
   }
   return searchTourFragment;
   ```
3. Avoid deleting your desired fragment by override destroyItem().

   ```
   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
       if(position != POSITION_OF_SEARCHTOURFRAGMENT) container.removeView((View)object);
   }
   ```

This is trying to keep your desired fragment from page change. But if you start another Activity and then back, the fragment may not be retained. Hope that helps!